# How to set interface visibility from a non static class ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class to hold the interface for different days of the week. I am passing the table cells to that class and applying it to a list. But when I loop through my class and call my HideInterface method it doesn't set the visibility of the interface. What am I missing? In my example i'm expecting to not see Tuesday. I'm convinced it's something to do with making the properties static but I can't quite crack it.

```
private static List<DayOfWeek> days = new List<DayOfWeek>();

private static List<WhatsMyDay> myDays = new List<WhatsMyDay>();

  public class WhatsMyDay
  {
    public WhatsMyDay(DayOfWeek day, DropDownList am, 
                        DropDownList pm, HtmlTableCell dTitle)
    {
        Day = day;
        ddlAM = am;
        ddlPM = pm;
        tdTitle = dTitle;
    }

    public DayOfWeek Day { get; private set; }
    private static DropDownList ddlAM { get; set; }
    private static DropDownList ddlPM { get; set; }
    private static HtmlTableCell tdTitle { get; set; }

    public int? AM
    {
        get { 
            return Convert.ToInt32(ddlAM.SelectedValue) == -1 
                ? null 
                : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlAM.SelectedValue); 
        }
    }

    public int? PM
    {
        get { 
            return Convert.ToInt32(ddlPM.SelectedValue) == -1 
                    ? null 
                    : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(ddlPM.SelectedValue); 
        }
    }

    public void ShowHideInterface(bool visiblity)
    {
        tdTitle.Visible = visiblity;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    days.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday);
    myDays.Add(new WhatsMyDay(
            DayOfWeek.Monday, ddlMondayAM, ddlMondayPM, tdMondayTitle));

    myDays.Add(new WhatsMyDay(
            DayOfWeek.Tuesday, ddlTuesdayAM, ddlTuesdayPM, tdTuesdayTitle));

    foreach (WhatsMyDay dayo in myDays)
    {
        dayo.ShowHideInterface(days.Contains(dayo.Day));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your code? Is it to render a series of days (in a table) and show/hide each day based on the contents of `List<DayOfWeek> days`?

Comment: That's the very core of it. I have it working, but I wanted to make it more efficient by creating a class structure to loop through rather than being so procedural about it. I wanted to set the days divs, cells and dropdowns etc to a class that I can call as and when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

If `DayOfWeek` is an enum (which is not shown there) the behavior would be described as:

since you're only adding `Monday` to the `days` variable, only `Monday` will be visible, because only this reduced expression is true: `[DayOfWeek.Monday].Contains(DayOfWeek.Monday)`

making `visiblity` for `ShowHideInterface` only true in that iteration of the loop.

If not, what is `DayOfWeek` ?

As for the static props, you should change them to non-static, since static will make them shared by all instances of `WhatsMyDay` and that doesn't seem to be your goal at all.

Comment: `DayOfWeek` is a standard BCL enum present in, as far as I know, all version of the framework.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, you might want to mention that Html elements are visible by default.  Thus negating the `Contains` check would yield the result the OP is looking for.

Comment: What I'm saying is my tablecell is not being set to visible true / false regardless of what happens with this code. It is always showing as true. I am expecting Monday to show and Tuesday to disspear. But despite (after stepping through the code and the td being set to visible = false, it is still showing on the interface. DayOfWeek is a .Net enum of days of the week.

Comment: you set it to false and it's not set? @MrSmith

Comment: Exactly. I set it to false and code side it says that the control with the correct ID against it is visible=false. But it still shows on the interface.